# ¿Comparar elementos de un array?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

[image: [![> Cita en bloque][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2t6a.png]

De mi JSON obtengo los primeros 15 registros con el id de un cajero similar y luego siguen otros 13 con un id diferente que es el 121, quiero comparar esos valores si es diferente dejar un espacio y si no lo es no dejar espacio.

He intentado lo siguiente :

```
function generarCards(array) {
    // Array de objetos con propiedades v1 , v2 , v3 , v4 y v5 = id del objeto
    let datos = array.data;
    // Recorre el array
    for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            //Declare una variable para hacerlo más legible y obtengo lo que se ve en la foto
            let id = datos[i].v5
            console.log(id);
            // Declare un contador con uno mayor al de i para comparar con el siguiente objeto
            let j = i + 1
            // Comparo la posicion actual con una adelante
            if (id != datos[j].v5) {
                    console.log('dejar espacio');
            } else {
                    console.log('no se deja espacio');
            }
    }
```

Sin embargo se pierden unos registros como pueden observar en la primera foto sale cuantos registros tengo con cada id de cajero supongo que por el contador j y además me sale un error ya que suma una posición más de la longitud del array ¿Cómo podría compararlo sin los errores mencionados?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El propósito de esto es separar la información por el id de cajero ya que cuando los muestro salen todos juntos muchas gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo que se pierda ningún registro, el único problema que veo es lo de que se pase del índice máximo, eso ocurre en tu `if`. Porque estás poniendo que `j` sea `i + 1`, y cuando `i` está en el último elemento, `j` va a tener un valor fuera del rango permitido.

Cambia la condición de tu `if` por:  `if ((j < datos.length) && (id != datos[j].v5))`

Sobre perderse registros, puedes ver fácilmente, que en la primera foto tienes 15 mensajes iguales, luego 13, luego 14, 13, 14, 14, verdad?

En la segunda foto verás que: No dejas espacio 14 veces, luego espacio, no espacio 12 veces, luego espacio, no espacio 13 veces, luego espacio, etc.

Si te das cuenta, en el último mensaje de la primera foto, se deja espacio (que es lo que quieres), pero no se está saltando nada. A menos que no esté interpretando bien tus fotos.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario  añadí la condición que mencionaste y funcionó sin embargo me juntaba el ultimo id diferente así que cambie el valor de j = i - 1 y obtuve lo que buscaba.